# java parsing of complex string?

Tags: java

I am getting a string response from server like this..

```
[
 Anchor{anchorName='&loreal_lip_balm',
    clientName='loreal india',

  anchorPrice=10,
        campaigns=[
                Campaign{
                        campaignId='loreal_camp1',

                        question='How to Turn Your Melted Lipstick into a Tinted Lip Balm',

                        startDate=2015-08-04,
                        endDate=2015-08-04,
                        imageURL='null',

                        regionCountry='ALL',
                        rewardInfo='null',
                        campaignPrice=20,

                        options=null
              }
      ]},
    Anchor{

            anchorName='&loreal_total_repair_5',
            clientName='loreal india',
            anchorPrice=125,

          campaigns=[
                    Campaign{
                    campaignId='loreal_camp2',
                            question='Is it a good
                         product to buy?',
                            startDate=2015-08-04,
                            endDate=2015-08-04,

                         imageURL='null',
                            regionCountry='ALL',
                            rewardInfo='null',

                         campaignPrice=20,
                            options=null
                    }
                ]
       }
 ].
```

can anybody tell me how to parse this.It is not a json response.

Comment: The easiest way would be Scala's magic [parser-combinator](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Parser+Combinators--Getting+Started) framework. Scala runs of the JVM so you can then use your parsing library directly from Java. The alternative would be to use a library like[jparsec](https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec). I would not recommend parsing this yourself by hand.

Comment: What is your expected parsed result?

Comment: i need to get anchroname ,clientname,anchorprice ,campaigns values

Comment: proper response format

Comment: The response seems to have arrays and maps. If you are comfortable in Java a simple recursive descent parser seems to be a good bet.

Comment: @user2451997 please check an answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion.

I assume as you said that your input from the server is String.

I have build a little method that return the value of the required key.

```
public String valueFinder(String data, String key){

    int keyValueStart = data.indexOf(key) + key.length() + 1;
    String keyValueRaw = data.substring(keyValueStart, data.length());
    int keyValueEnd = keyValueRaw.indexOf(",");
    String keyValue = keyValueRaw.substring(0, keyValueEnd);
    String value = keyValue.replaceAll("^\'|\'$", "");

    return value;
}
```

So if you pass the String data generated by the server to the method and the ask for the required key for example for `"clientName"` it will return `loreal india`, if you pass/look-for `"anchorName"` it will return `&loreal_lip_balm`.

Now you have the concept, you are welcome to change/modify/customize it as you wish to fetch more detailed information in your campaigns or other scenarios.

It is possible to further develop the method to return single key value, a set of keys and values, convert keys and values to JSON or Array, and just name it.

All this can be done on the same concept.

Answer (score 2):

I used hand coded parsers for simple languages where I felt that using http://www.antlr.org/ or https://javacc.java.net to be a bit heavy. I used the same structure for parsing JSON, CSS a simple template. Modified it to parse your response. See whether it helps.

```
package snippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PushbackReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import snippet.RecursiveDescentParser.Token.TokenType;

public class RecursiveDescentParser {

    // @formatter:off
    final static String text = "" +
            "[" + 
            " Anchor{anchorName='&loreal_lip_balm'," + 
            "    clientName='loreal india'," + 
            "" + 
            "  anchorPrice=10," + 
            "        campaigns=[" + 
            "                Campaign{" + 
            "                        campaignId='loreal_camp1'," + 
            "" + 
            "                        question='How to Turn Your Melted Lipstick into a Tinted Lip Balm'," + 
            "" + 
            "                        startDate=2015-08-04," + 
            "                        endDate=2015-08-04," + 
            "                        imageURL='null'," + 
            "" + 
            "                        regionCountry='ALL'," + 
            "                        rewardInfo='null'," + 
            "                        campaignPrice=20," + 
            "" + 
            "                        options=null" + 
            "              }" + 
            "      ]}," + 
            "    Anchor{" + 
            "" + 
            "            anchorName='&loreal_total_repair_5'," + 
            "            clientName='loreal india'," + 
            "            anchorPrice=125," + 
            "" + 
            "          campaigns=[" + 
            "                    Campaign{" + 
            "                    campaignId='loreal_camp2'," + 
            "                            question='Is it a good" + 
            "                         product to buy?'," + 
            "                            startDate=2015-08-04," + 
            "                            endDate=2015-08-04," + 
            "" + 
            "                         imageURL='null'," + 
            "                            regionCountry='ALL'," + 
            "                            rewardInfo='null'," + 
            "" + 
            "                         campaignPrice=20," + 
            "                            options=null" + 
            "                    }" + 
            "                ]" + 
            "       }" + 
            " ]" + 
            "";
    // @formatter:on

    static class Token {
        enum TokenType {
            OPEN_BRACKET, CLOSE_BRACKET, OPEN_BRACE, CLOSE_BRACE, STRING, NAME, COMMA, EQUALS, INTEGER, DATE, EOF, NULL;
        }

        private String text;
        private TokenType type;

        public Token(TokenType type) {
            this(type, null);
        }

        public Token(TokenType type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public TokenType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return "Token [text=" + text + ", type=" + type + "]";
        }

    }

    static class TokenReader {
        private PushbackReader reader;

        public TokenReader(Reader reader) {
            this.reader = new PushbackReader(reader);
        }

        public Token nextToken() throws IOException {
            Token t = nextTokenx();
            System.out.println("Got: " + t);
            return t;
        }

        public Token nextTokenx() throws IOException {
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1 && Character.isWhitespace((char) c))
                ;
            if (c == -1)
                return new Token(TokenType.EOF);
            switch (c) {
            case '[':
                return new Token(TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET);
            case ']':
                return new Token(TokenType.CLOSE_BRACKET);
            case '{':
                return new Token(TokenType.OPEN_BRACE);
            case '}':
                return new Token(TokenType.CLOSE_BRACE);
            case ',':
                return new Token(TokenType.COMMA);
            case '=':
                return new Token(TokenType.EQUALS);
            default:
                if (Character.isDigit(c))
                    return readIntegerOrDate(c);
                if (c == '\'')
                    return readString(c);
                if (Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c))
                    return readName(c);
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid character '" + ((char) c) + "' in input");
            }
        }

        private Token readName(int c) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append((char) c);
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1 && Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c))
                sb.append((char) c);
            if (c != -1)
                reader.unread(c);
            if ("null".equals(sb.toString()))
                return new Token(TokenType.NULL);
            return new Token(TokenType.NAME, sb.toString());
        }

        private Token readString(int end) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1 && c != end)
                sb.append((char) c);
            return new Token(TokenType.STRING, sb.toString());
        }

        private Token readIntegerOrDate(int c) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append((char) c);
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1 && Character.isDigit((char) c))
                sb.append((char) c);
            if (c == '-') {
                sb.append((char) c);
                return readDate(sb);
            }
            if (c != -1)
                reader.unread(c);
            return new Token(TokenType.INTEGER, sb.toString());
        }

        private Token readDate(StringBuilder sb) throws IOException {
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1 && Character.isDigit((char) c))
                sb.append((char) c);
            if (c == -1)
                throw new RuntimeException("EOF while reading date");
            if (c != '-')
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid character '" + (char) c + "' while reading date");
            sb.append((char) c);
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1 && Character.isDigit((char) c))
                sb.append((char) c);
            if (c != -1)
                reader.unread(c);
            return new Token(TokenType.DATE, sb.toString());
        }
    }

    static class Lexer {

        private TokenReader reader;
        private Token current;

        public Lexer(Reader reader) {
            this.reader = new TokenReader(reader);
        }

        public Token expect(TokenType... tt) throws IOException {
            if (current == null)
                current = reader.nextToken();
            for (TokenType tokenType : tt) {
                if (current.getType() == tokenType) {
                    Token r = current;
                    current = null;
                    return r;
                }
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Expecting one of " + Arrays.asList(tt) + " but got " + current);
        }

        public Token expect1or0(TokenType... tt) throws IOException {
            if (current == null)
                current = reader.nextToken();
            for (TokenType tokenType : tt) {
                if (current.getType() == tokenType) {
                    Token r = current;
                    current = null;
                    return r;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object parse(String text) throws IOException {
        return parse(new StringReader(text));
    }

    private Object parse(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        Lexer lexer = new Lexer(reader);
        return parse(lexer);
    }

    private Object parse(Lexer lexer) throws IOException {
        Token t = lexer.expect1or0(TokenType.OPEN_BRACE, TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET, TokenType.EOF);
        if (t == null || t.getType() == TokenType.EOF)
            return null;
        else if (t.getType() == TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET) {
            return parseList(lexer);
        } else {
            return parseMap(null, lexer);
        }
    }

    private List<Object> parseList(Lexer lexer) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Token tName = lexer.expect1or0(TokenType.NAME);
        while (tName != null) {
            lexer.expect(TokenType.OPEN_BRACE);
            result.add(parseMap(tName.getText(), lexer));
            if (lexer.expect1or0(TokenType.COMMA) != null)
                tName = lexer.expect(TokenType.NAME);
            else
                tName = null;
        }
        lexer.expect(TokenType.CLOSE_BRACKET);
        return result;
    }

    private Object parseMap(String oname, Lexer lexer) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (oname != null)
            result.put("objectName", oname);
        Token tName = lexer.expect1or0(TokenType.NAME);
        while (tName != null) {
            String name = tName.getText();
            lexer.expect(TokenType.EQUALS);
            Token next = lexer.expect(TokenType.STRING, TokenType.DATE, TokenType.INTEGER, TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET,
                    TokenType.OPEN_BRACE, TokenType.NULL);
            TokenType tt = next.getType();
            if (tt == TokenType.STRING) {
                result.put(name, next.getText());
            } else if (tt == TokenType.DATE) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                try {
                    result.put(name, sdf.parse(next.getText()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            } else if (tt == TokenType.INTEGER) {
                result.put(name, Integer.valueOf(next.getText()));
            } else if (tt == TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET) {
                result.put(name, parseList(lexer));
            } else if (tt == TokenType.OPEN_BRACE) {
                result.put(name, parseMap(null, lexer));
            } else {
                result.put(name, null);
            }
            if (lexer.expect1or0(TokenType.COMMA) != null)
                tName = lexer.expect(TokenType.NAME);
            else
                tName = null;
        }
        lexer.expect(TokenType.CLOSE_BRACE);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RecursiveDescentParser parser = new RecursiveDescentParser();
        Object o = parser.parse(text);
        System.out.println(o);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which is useful to read data like this.